# plot two shapes above the candle on Trading View

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

How can I plot two shapes (flag and circle) using pine script in Trading view?

I have tried using location.absolute method, but it is not showing the property and there is a gap between the shapes for certain stock symbols.

`plotshape(high+5  , "S1", style = shape.circle,  location = location.absolute, color = color.red) plotshape(high+10  , "S1", style = shape.xcross,  location = location.absolute, color = color.blue)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the value of high, plus a percentage
Something like that:

```
plotshape(data ? high+high*0.05 : na , "S1", style = shape.circle,  location = location.absolute, color = color.red)
plotshape(data ? high+high*0.10 : na , "S1", style = shape.xcross,  location = location.absolute, color = color.blue)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, the issue has not been resolved. I am still experiencing gaps, and these gaps vary depending on different time frame (daily, weekly, monthly, etc.), stock price range (100, 1000, 10000), also when switching to log scale. Is there a way to read y-axis scale information?

Comment: can you upload an image with the problem?

Comment: `indicator(title="Test Indicator", shorttitle="Test_Indicator", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

plotshape(data ? high+high*0.05 : na , "S1", style = shape.circle,  location = location.absolute, color = color.red)
plotshape(data ? high+high*0.10 : na , "S1", style = shape.xcross,  location = location.absolute, color = color.blue)`
Monthly Chart: [link](https://www.tradingview.com/x/NjoAW7Aj/)
Weekly Chart: [link]( https://www.tradingview.com/x/F07PJy6P/)
Same code on Berkshire Hathway daily chart: [link](https://www.tradingview.com/x/BM16xi3h/)